# SUMPRODUCT inside ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a fixed vector, say $A$1:$E$1

I also have a vector per row, say A2:E2, A3:E3, A4:E4...

Now I want output in Column F as

```
F2 = sumproduct(A1:E1,A2:E2)
F3 = sumproduct(A1:E1,A3:E3)
F4 = sumproduct(A1:E1,A4:E4)
...
```

Now I want to put these into one array formula, but I don't know how to do it. For example

```
F2 = Arrayformula(sumproduct($A$1:$E$1,A2:A:E2:E))
```

Meaning multiply A1-E1 vector with A2:E2, then A3:E3 and so on.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E), 
 MMULT(A1:E1*A2:E,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E1)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a bit trouble parsing the formula but seems to work.

Comment: I have played around with this "=A2:A&B2:B&C2:C" and I have no idea what it does. It just gets some of the cells as a string but for a life of me it seems so random what cells it gets. Can you clarify?

And then Length of that, ok. But then IF that length? What does that do?

Comment: COLUMN(A1:E1) just returns a single digit of the column, that to ^0 is then just always "1" isn't it?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XFMDmP8xBH5PzEWD8Stk7FHWMVkTgbxVLG_xrF4mtms/)

The cell I wanted to put this into is 
idx!AB12

The fixed vector is idx!P8:AA8 and the row of vectors is idx!D12:D ... O12:O

Comment: paste this where you need to: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(P8:AA8*IFERROR(D12:O),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(P8:AA8)^0)))`

Comment: or perhaps you want this? `=ARRAYFORMULA(AB8*MMULT(P8:AA8*IFERROR(1+D12:O),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(P8:AA8)^0)))`

Comment: The last one is perfect, thank you. I'm gonna have to figure out what it all means but that is great :)